# Sitecore Analytics not working in Sitecore 9.2 JSS Application

Tags: jss, experience-analytics

I have enabled the following settings

```
<setting name="Sitecore.JSS.TrackerServiceEnabled" value="true" />
<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />
<setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true" />
```

Still I get following errors in log file

```
2012 16:23:26 DEBUG [Analytics]: Tracker.IsActive == false. EndAnalytics pipeline is terminated
2012 16:23:26 DEBUG Tracker is not initialized. ReleaseContact processor is skipped
```

I have also set session timeout to 1 minute.

Console screenshot
[image]

Any other configurations to enable?

Comment: Any error in logs or browser console?

Comment: No..not anything specific to tracking. I have added the screenshot in question

Comment: Whenever Sitecore starts it will print system settings, one of them is - if tracking is allowed by license, like

`INFO xDB is enabled.`

`Tracking is enabled`  

`Valid xDB license is present`

Do you have similar lines in your log file?

Comment: Yes.I am able to see following lines.  
15496 12:49:05 INFO  xDB is enabled.
15496 12:49:05 INFO  
15496 12:49:05 INFO  Tracking is enabled.
15496 12:49:05 INFO  
15496 12:49:05 INFO  Valid xDB license is present.
15496 12:49:05 INFO  
15496 12:49:05 INFO